# wrong syntax in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyadmin and mysql to compile my database, I am trying to debug a constraint trouble I am getting so I trying to perform this code below:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```

But it is saying that it is the wrong syntax,

Does anybody know what the correct syntax is?

Comment: have u tried  just SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS.. this should work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\G` is only for mysql interactive client, I think phpmyadmin doesn't support it.

Just do the below instead:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```